# Execute wamp without asking Admin password (windows)

Tags: windows, apache, wamp, wampserver, privileges

I have a problem executing WampServer on my user computer 
is there a way to permit the user execute WampServer and to restart Apache server without having to enter Admin password ?

Answer (score 1):

1. login as an administrator;
2. Install wamp
3. Download subinacl.exe from microsoft: 
   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23510
4. grant permissions to the regular user account to manage the WAMP services:
   (subinacl.exe is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Resource Kits\Tools)

subinacl /SERVICE \MachineName\wampapache /GRANT=domainname.com\username=F

subinacl /SERVICE \MachineName\wampmysql /GRANT=domainname.com\username=F

5. logout and log back in as the user. They should now be able to launch the WAMP taskbar application and control the WAMP service.

copied from my pc solved problem document nd forget wheres the source link hope that work

Comment: This worked for me but needed two backward slashes before the MachineName, e.g. \\MachineName